# Align 0 value of Y-axis at the middle of container in Plotly.js

Tags: d3.js, plotly, plotly.js

Playing with [Plotly.js](https://plotly.com/javascript/) and need to make stacked bar chart with positive and negative values, but in such a way that 0 value of Y-axis will be aligned in the middle of the container, how can I achieve it?

This is my playground where I get stuck: https://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/oNjopvR

Right now my layout is as following, but it's better to look at my codepen example to get the whole picture.

```
const layout = {
        yaxis: {
          visible: true,
          constraintoward: 'center',
          showticklabels: false
        },
        xaxis: {
          visible: false
        },
        barmode: 'relative',
        showlegend: false,
        margin: {
          l: 0,
          r: 0,
          t: 0,
          b: 0
        },
        autosize: true,
        height: 200,
        width: 100,
        displayModeBar: false
      };
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set the Y axis range manually.

```
const dataN = [trace1, trace2];
const dataP = [trace3, trace4];

const alldata = [...trace1.y, ...trace2.y, ...trace3.y, ...trace4.y];
const maxValue = Math.max(...alldata.map( e => Math.abs(e)));

var layout = {
   yaxis: {
      visible: true,
      constraintoward: 'center',
      showticklabels: false,
      range: [-maxValue,maxValue]
    },
```

[Code pen fork](https://codepen.io/mpbastos/pen/KKdyQrP)

Comment: Thank you very much!